# How can I make layout like this with inflated layout?

Tags: android

I inflate layout to listview and here is what I want:

[image]

But I always get something like this:

[image]

As you see, the button is always align at the bottom of parent. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_icon_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_icon_type"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_post_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title_type"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_icon_type"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_post_time"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_icon_type"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_edit_post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="openPostMenu"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_memo_menu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_icon_type"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_posted"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_status"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_posted"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_posted"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_posted" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_confirm_route"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="#f2f2f2" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/現在地からのル一トを確認" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20sp"
                    android:layout_height="20sp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_address"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_memo_route_search_pressed" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to fix this!Thank you!

Comment: its card view read about it here https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: I don't want to use cardview. Is any way I can do without it?

Comment: Like mentionned above its a CardView, if you dont want to use it, you can do something similar but first you need to create a custom background for the shadows, and then add some margins to your View.